# Concatenate Consecutive Integers in Java String

Tags: java, string, parsing, char

I am trying for find the Java code which:

1) Checks whether the String contains any consecutive integers

2) If it contains consecutive integers, then concatenate them i.e. my current message has integers separated by space only, so I need a way to concatenate those space separate integers. Eg:

```
message1 = "My no is 9543 21 00 10"
desired output = "My no is 9543210010"

message2 = "You can reach 2 me at 42315 468"
desired output = "You can reach 2 me at 42315468"
```

My main problem is to solve the above issue for phone numbers ie to concatenate space separated phone numbers together, so if someone has a different approach to solve this, please let me know.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work when string ends with a space:

```
if(message.matches(".*\\d.*")){             
    for (int i = 0; i <= message.length() -2 ; ++i){             
        if ((Character.isDigit(message.charAt(i))) && message.charAt(i+1) == ' ' && (Character.isDigit(message.charAt(i+2))))  {                        
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
            sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
            message = sb.toString();
        }
    }                       
}
```

Comment: In other words, you are trying to remove spaces which are surrounded by digits. Try with `message = message.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=\\d)","");`

Comment: @Pshemo That should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @TimB Based on problem description I suspect that provided example may be oversimplified which is why I posted only comment instead of answer (I don't like posting answers if I suspect it will need to be corrected because someone didn't provide all necessary info). I was hoping that OP will respond with some real case on which this solution will not work, then we can start thinking at real answer. But lets hope I was wrong :)

Comment: your solution worked for me @Pshemo

Comment: okay will do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A community wiki answer based on peshmo's comment.

In other words, you are trying to remove spaces which are surrounded by digits.

```
message = message.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=\\d)","");
```

This regex expression will do that. Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/qR33XN/1

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, just written in notepad but I think you will get the gist.

Basicly, split the string into an array with delimiter of a space(' '), glue everything back together. Add a space if index + 1 isn't a number otherwise don't add a space.

I hope this helps

```
String msg = "abc 1 2 3 333 yoo"
String[] splitted = msg.Split(' ');
String output = "";

for(int i = 0; i < splitted.Length - 1; i++) {

    output += splitted[i];
    if(i + 1 < splitted.Length - 1) {
        if(isInteger(splitted[i]) && isInteger(splitted[i+1]))
            continue;   
    }
    output += " " 
}
output = output.Trim();

public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    // only got here if we didn't return false
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If this overly verbose code is for educational purposes, there are a few things inside you should note:
* do not forget the ; at the end of the line (ok, you stated it's untested)
* do not rely on Exceptions for normal program flow
* do not concatenate Strings in loops - use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: It's  just a proof of concept thingy; just to get the point across

Comment: This would work but there are far simpler ways. For example see the CW answer I just posted.

Comment: If you are new to programming (which I imply from the question) it's more easier to understand to split things up and glue them back together than start learning RegEx right away imo.